# smbtree produces no output

Tags: 14.04, samba

Ubuntu 14.04 installed. Also installed samba, system-config-samba, samba-common-bin, samba-common, smbclient, nautilus-share, fusemb, winbind, and cifs-utils, among others.

I'm trying to get Samba to work. Right now I have machines running either Ubuntu 14.04 or Lubuntu 14.04, but will soon be adding a Windows box to the mix. I call my workgroup, "workgroup".

After installing all the packages listed above, I thought the first thing I should do is make sure all is in order. So, I ran testparm:

```
main1@system1:~$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[shared_stuff]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    guest account = main1
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    name resolve order = bcast, host
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    guest ok = Yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    printable = Yes
    print ok = Yes
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[shared_stuff]
    path = /home/main1/shared_stuff
    read only = No
```

I then ran `smbtree`, expecting to see the shared `shared_stuff` in the output, but instead got nothing for the output:

```
main1@system1:~$ smbtree
Enter main1's password: 
main1@system1:~$
```

I have looked all over the internet for any posting by an earthling regarding no output for smbtree, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I also ran `smbtree -d3`:

```
main1@system1:~$ smbtree -d3
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
Processing section "[global]"
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.1.2 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Enter main1's password: 
tdb(/var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name WORKGROUP<0x1d>
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7f06594e7800] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name WORKGROUP<0x1b>
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7f06594e7770] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
name_resolve_bcast: Attempting broadcast lookup for name __MSBROWSE__<0x1>
samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x7f06594e7800] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[7] - disabling
```

And, I do not have `ufw` running:

```
main1@system1:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for main1: 
Status: inactive
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `browseable` option. It needs to go like this if you want to see it with `smbtree`:

```
[shared_stuff]
   path = /home/main1/shared_stuff
   read only = No
   browseable = Yes
```

Then do `sudo service smbd restart` and now you can run `smbtree` and you will see it.

Comment: Thanks Luis.  

I added the "browseable = Yes" line, restarted smbd (and nmbd), waited about five minutes, ran smbtree, no change, still no output.  

Any other thoughts?

Comment: I would first try to start from a clean Samba configuration file. At the moment I do not have an idea (Working on something else) but my suggestion would be that. It can simplify where the problem is appearing when you tested this.

Comment: In case this helps anyone else......  

I stumbled across this, it appears to have solved my problem, but......  Well, I'll explain my "but" further on below.  

In the [Global] section of the Samba configuration file, I entered these two parameters: 

preferred master = Yes
    domain master = Yes

After making just that change, smbtree works, and the computer can now "see" the other computers. 


I still wonder if I have *really* solved the problem.  I read about these two parameters, I have to say I don't fully understand the true purpose of them nor their full impacts.

Comment: @dln949 Depends if you are in a domain or workgroup. On the type of authentication, on how the network works and other factors. I normally do not explain that until the user tells me the network topology, domain type, client types, etc.. Too many answers when they use that many options.

Answer (score 1):

You get the same problems if you secure your smb connection by authentification, and kerberos etc. isn't installed correctly. Try to **remove or comment-out** these lines if nothing else works:

```
server signing = mandatory 
smb encrypt = mandatory
```